# Issue on root controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a view controller that loads just fine whenever I navigate to it within my app. However, when I try to make that page the root view from my app delegate it crashes stating that one of my labels is not key value coding-compliant for the key. Again, this error only happens if the view is the root view. Here is the line that I am using to push to this page as a root view:

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PrivacyView" bundle:nil];
```

Is there something wrong with the way I have this set up to cause this crash?

Comment: Not coding compliant ? Could you show the exact error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to allocate a new `UIViewController`. There is a high probability that this is not the class you want.

Look inside the `PrivacyView` xib file and see the name of the controller that you have to use:

[image]

In this example, you would have to call:

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[ListMenuHeader alloc] initWithNibName:@"PrivacyView" bundle:nil];
```